# label.enabled and label.visible will not update on System.Windows.Forms.timer.tick event VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, winforms, timer, label

Can anyone please let me know where I have gone wrong here? the label will not give a blinking effect when the `blinkTimer` is supposed to hit it's tick event. It acts almost as if the tick event never gets fired or the `blinkTimer.Start()` doesn't actually start the timer.

This code is in a Windows form, so you will need to add the following to a form designer:
label, DateTimePicker, Button

And set the following in the properties panel:

```
label name = timerLabel
DatetimePicker name = timePicker
button name = startStop

timerLabel.text = "00:00:00"
timePicker.Format = Custom
timePicker.CustomerFormat = "  HH  :  mm  :  ss"
timePicker.ShowUpDown = True
timePicker.Value = 2/12/2014 1:00 AM
startStop.text = "Start"
```

(I thinks that's all the properties I set that are relevant)

And here is the large block of code:

```
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.Math
Imports System.Timers

Public Class stopwatch
    Private timeTimer As System.Windows.Forms.Timer = New System.Windows.Forms.Timer()
    Private length As TimeSpan = New TimeSpan(1, 0, 0)
    Private formatTimer As System.Timers.Timer
    Private blinkStatus As Boolean = False
    Private WithEvents blinkTimer As System.Windows.Forms.Timer = New System.Windows.Forms.Timer()


    Private Sub setTimeLength()
        length = New TimeSpan(Me.timePicker.Value.Hour, Me.timePicker.Value.Minute, Me.timePicker.Value.Second)
    End Sub

    Private Sub startStop_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles startStop.Click
        setTimeLength()
        initializeTimeTimer()
        setFormatTimer((length.TotalMilliseconds / 4) * 3)
        timeTimer.Start()
        formatTimer.Start()
    End Sub

    Private Sub initializeTimeTimer()
        timeTimer.Interval = 1000
        AddHandler timeTimer.Tick, AddressOf timetimer_tick
    End Sub

    Private Sub timetimer_tick(Optional sender As Object = Nothing, Optional e As System.EventArgs = Nothing)
        If length.TotalSeconds = 0 Then timerLabel.ForeColor = Color.Red
        timerLabel.Text = length.ToString
        length = length.Subtract(New TimeSpan(0, 0, 1))
    End Sub

    Private Sub timePicker_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles timePicker.TextChanged
        Dim hours As String = Me.timePicker.Value.Hour
        Dim minutes As String = Me.timePicker.Value.Minute
        Dim seconds As String = Me.timePicker.Value.Second
        If Len(hours) = 1 Then hours = "0" & hours
        If Len(minutes) = 1 Then minutes = "0" & minutes
        If Len(seconds) = 1 Then seconds = "0" & seconds
        timerLabel.Text = String.Format("{0}:{1}:{2}", hours, minutes, seconds)
    End Sub

    Private Sub stopwatch_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        timerLabel.Text = length.ToString
        blinkTimer.Interval = 500

    End Sub

    Private Sub setFormatTimer(ByVal intervalValue As Integer)
        formatTimer = New System.Timers.Timer(intervalValue)
        AddHandler formatTimer.Elapsed, AddressOf formatTimer_elapsed
    End Sub

    Private Sub formatTimer_elapsed(sender As Object, e As ElapsedEventArgs)
        If timerLabel.ForeColor = Color.Lime Then
            timerLabel.ForeColor = Color.Yellow
            formatTimer.Stop()
            setFormatTimer((length.TotalMilliseconds / 3) * 2)
            formatTimer.Start()
        ElseIf timerLabel.ForeColor = Color.Yellow Then
            timerLabel.ForeColor = Color.Red
            formatTimer.Stop()
            setFormatTimer(length.TotalMilliseconds)
            formatTimer.Start()

        ElseIf timerLabel.ForeColor = Color.Red Then
            formatTimer.Stop()
            blinkTimer.Start()
            Console.WriteLine("blinking should be started")
            blinkStatus = True
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub blinkTimer_tick(Optional sender As Object = Nothing, Optional e As EventArgs = Nothing) Handles blinkTimer.Tick
        Console.WriteLine("blinkTimer.tick is a go")
        If timerLabel.Enabled = True Then
            timerLabel.Visible = False
            timerLabel.Enabled = False
        Else
            timerLabel.Visible = True
            timerLabel.Enabled = True
        End If    
    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try removing the InvokeRequired part and see if that works, or put a MsgBox above the if statement just to see if it is even firing the tick event.

Comment: I have added a `console.WriteLine()` as the first statement of the sub. I then took out the delegate and the invocation if statement.  under both conditions, the `blinkTimer_tick()` is not being called on the tick event. I have updated the code in the first post to reflect the changes